# Perform hyperlink by hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

I have a very little problem. I want to go on another site, by hovering an "a"-link (like clicking the link, just without the click :) ). Is this possible with css? If yes, how do you do that?

Comment: maybe Not, but it is possible with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's absolutely not possible with `CSS`, as far as I know, but you can do it with pure `JavaScript` or with any advanced `JavaScript` library.

I'm gonna give you a simple solution:

```
<a onmouseover="this.click();" href="...">link</a>
```

Or, if you want to use `jQuery`:

```
$('a').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.querySelector('#your_a_id').onmouseover = function()
 {
     window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com"; 
 }
```

a way using javascript :)

Comment: Was the answer any helpful to you?

Answer (score -1):

```
onmouseover="function()"

window.location.href = "https://www.example.com";
```

now you can go on a URL just hovering over it.